# Find a slot's group when Kendo scheduler resource grouping is used

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Kendo scheduler resource grouping and slots. 
I have a kendo scheduler with horizontal resource grouping. How to find the resource group of a selected slot or cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of the group can be found by,

```
function scheduler_change(e) {
    // the index of the group
    var index = $("#scheduler").data('kendoScheduler').slotByElement(e.slots[0].element).groupIndex;

    // from the resource array, resource[index] gives the required object
}
```